# Differences between using Sagemaker notebook vs Glue (Sagemaker) notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Machine Learning job I want to run with Sagemaker. For data preparation and transformation, I am using some numpy and pandas steps to transform them with notebook.

I noticed AWS Glue have both [Sagemaker and Zeppelin notebook which can be created via development endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html)

There isn't much info online i could find what's the difference and benefit of using one over another (i.e. Sagemaker notebook and import from s3 vs creating notebook from Glue)

From what i researched and tried it seems that i can achieve same thing with both:

- Sagemaker notebook and import directly from s3 + further python code to process the data
- Glue (need to crawl and create dataset) as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html#aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators-crawling), create dev endpoint and use similar script to process the data.

Anyone able to shed light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question isn't clear but let me explain this point.

When you launch a Glue Development endpoint you can attach either a SageMaker notebook or Zeppelin notebook. Both will be created and configured by Glue and your script will be executed on the Glue Dev endpoint.

**If your question is "what is the difference between a SageMaker notebook created from Glue console and a SageMaker notebook created from SageMaker console?**

When you create a notebook instance from Glue console, the created notebook will always have public internet access enabled. [This blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/understanding-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-networking-configurations-and-advanced-routing-options/) explains the difference between the networking configurations with SM notebooks. You cannot also create the notebook with a specific disk size but you can stop the notebook once it's created and increase disk size.

**If your question is "what is the difference between SageMaker notebook and Zeppelin notebooks?"**

The answer is the first one used Jupter (very popular) while the second one uses Zeppelin.

**If your question is "what is the difference between using only a SageMaker notebook versus using SM notebook + Glue dev Endpoint?"**

The answer is: if you are running normal pandas + numpy without using Spark, SM notebook is much cheaper (if you use small instance type and if your data is relatively small). However, if you are trying to process a large dataset and you are planning to use spark, then SM notebook + Glue Dev endpoint will be the best option to develop the job which will be executed later as a Glue Job (transformation job) (server less).

SM notebook is like running python code on an EC2 instance versus SM notebook + Glue which is used to develop ETL jobs which you can launch to process deltas.

Comment: I was referring to the last "If your question is "what is the difference between using only a SageMaker notebook versus using SM notebook + Glue dev Endpoint?", thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only numpy and pandas, functions-wise it doesn't make a real difference. But it depends on your data as well, if you want to work with data sitting in a Glue table it would be easier to work with Zeppelin notebooks via an endpoint.

Costwise I am pretty sure that Sagemaker is less expensive.